# change PostgreSQL data directory

Tags: macos, postgresql, pgadmin

I installed postgres 9.5 quite a while ago, and since a few months ago have upgraded to 9.6 and used that.  Recently I shut down my computer and restarted postgres, but when I connect to the 9.6 server and run

`SHOW data_directory`

it is showing that my data directory is under the 9.5 folder.  As a result, none of my recent databases are available because I am linked to the old version of postgres.  What happened and how can I change it back?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that your machine has started your previous instance. You need to stop the 9.5 server and start the 9.6.

On *nix OS you will need to use the PG_CTL command. eg:

```
PG_CTL -D [enter path for 9.5 data directory here] stop
PG_CTL -D [enter path for 9.6 data directory here] start
```

This should stop 9.5 and start 9.6. You can confirm this by doing:

```
PG_CTL -D [enter path for 9.5 data directory here] status
```

should return stopped.

```
PG_CTL -D [enter path for 9.6 data directory here] status
```

should return running.